# How to solve equation in R?

Tags: r

[image]

How to turn "X" into a variable or a number so that the program performs arithmetic operations with it?

I tried to do this:

```
A <- matrix(c(1+x,x,x,x,2+x,x,x,x,3+x), nrow=3, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)

print(A) ##It gives an error here

det(A)

uravnenie<- det(A)==17

solve(uravnenie,x)
```

If we decide with our hands, we must get:

```
11x+6=17

x=1
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to write a function:

---

function to obtain the matrix determinant for a given `x`

```
mat_det <- function(x){
    det(matrix(c(1+x,x,x,x,2+x,x,x,x,3+x),3))
 }
```

---

Optimizing the function to obtain `x` s.t the determinant is 17:

```
optimise(\(x)(mat_det(x)-17)^2, c(-10,10))
$minimum
[1] 1

$objective
[1] 0
```

Check that the determinant at the minimum is indeed 17.

```
mat_det(1)
[1] 17
```